# SQL combine 2 tables in one column sepataring by comma

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Hello i have problem with SQL query, I want to combinate from 2 tables 5 columns and sepatate it with comma, below i post picture how tables look.

[image]

In the example :

name: length, j1: mm,  j2:cm, j3: NULL, j4: m

name: size, j1: NULL, j2: NULL, j3:NULL, j4:NULL;

the result after query i want to something like this:

[image]

if in rows I found NULL we should return " - "

I was try Concat but i dont know how to return - if I find blank row

Comment: I removed the Oracle tag because it looked like "the odd man out".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `coalesce()` and `concat_ws()`.  Something like this:

```
select concat_ws(',',
                 coalesce(name, '-'),
                 coalesce(j1, '-'),
                 coalesce(j2, '-'),
                 coalesce(j3, '-'),
                 coalesce(j4, '-')
                )
from t1 left join
     t2
     using (t2_id)
```

Comment: By the way do you know the way to do it with n column? for the example i have "j" from 1 to 100

Comment: @godislikemyquestionsrets . . . Just repeat the expression (you can use a spreadsheet to create the code).  It sounds like you have a problem with your data model if you have 100 such columns.  The values should probably be in rows.